# Create a Data Extension in Specific Folder via SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am creating a Data Extension on Marketing cloud via SOAP API and it works without issue. The data extension creates on root folder. But I need to create the same on a sub folder. (Data Extensions/Test/Samples)

Here is my code.

```
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>xxxx</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>xxxx</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <CreateRequest
        xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options>
            <SaveOptions/>
        </Options>
        <Objects xsi:type="DataExtension">
            <Client>
                <ID>7317455</ID>
            </Client>
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="false" />
            <Name>TEST_DE_2</Name>
            <Description>MKT_POC_DE_1</Description>
            <IsSendable>false</IsSendable>
            <IsTestable>false</IsTestable>
            <DataRetentionPeriodLength>48</DataRetentionPeriodLength>
            <DataRetentionPeriod>Days</DataRetentionPeriod>
            <RowBasedRetention>false</RowBasedRetention>
            <ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>true</ResetRetentionPeriodOnImport>
            <DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>false</DeleteAtEndOfRetentionPeriod>
            <Fields>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>F1_ID</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>F1_ID</Name>
                    <Description>F1_ID</Description>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>true</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <MaxLength>100</MaxLength>
                    <FieldType>Text</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue></DefaultValue>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <Name>F2_Email</Name>
                    <Description>F2_Email</Description>
                    <IsNillable>false</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>EmailAddress</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue></DefaultValue>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>F3_Date</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>F3_Date</Name>
                    <DataType>Date</DataType>
                    <Label>F3_Date</Label>
                    <IsNillable>true</IsNillable>
                    <IsPrimaryKey>false</IsPrimaryKey>
                    <FieldType>Date</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue>getdate()</DefaultValue>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <CustomerKey>F4_Decimal</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>F4_Decimal</Name>
                    <FieldType>Decimal</FieldType>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                    <Precision>10</Precision>
                    <Scale>2</Scale>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <Name>F5_Boolean</Name>
                    <FieldType>Boolean</FieldType>
                    <DefaultValue>true</DefaultValue>
                    <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
                </Field>
                <Field>
                    <Name>F6_Phone</Name>
                    <FieldType>Phone</FieldType>
                    <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                </Field>
            </Fields>
        </Objects>
    </CreateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass Folder ID as CategoryID - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/dataextension.htm

Comment: Hi, @MBB Thanks a lot for the reply, can you please tell me where to get the category Id of a specific folder and where to put it in the SOAP envelope??

Comment: You can make a separate call to retrieve DataFolder object by Name and ContentType:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_retrieving_updating_and_deleting_folders.htm?search_text=folder

Content type defines what object is stored in folder - in your case its 'dataextension' as stated here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/datafolder.htm?search_text=folder

Then you just pass it inside <Objects> as <CategoryId>